# Show that an abelian group isomorphic to the product of its subgroup and another abelian group.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Show that for abelian groups G, H such that there exist homomorphisms $f:G \to H$ and $g:H \to G$ and $g \circ f$ is the identity - H can be expressed as a direct product of G and another abelian group K.

My first thought was to see the image of $f$ and that there is an isomorphism from $g$ to $f(G)$.

Given that this is an abelian group, the subgroup is normal and so I thought that perhaps $G\ X\ H/G$ would be isomorphic to $H$ but according to the following page this approach is not entirely correct.

https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Question:Normal_subgroup_quotient_group_determine_whole_group

I am not sure what to do - should I construct a function explicitly $s.t.$ it takes the image of $f$ in $H$ through g and everything else not contained in the image to (1, h)? Also what if $H$ and $G$ are not commutative?

Comment: You mean that $g\circ f$ is the identity.

Comment: Use \to for a right arrow and \circ for composition.

Comment: you're correct! I meant $g \circ f$ is the identity.

Comment: This is the so called splitting lemma:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_lemma

Comment: @PaulK That's exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use different notation: $\phi:A\to B$ and $\psi:B\to A$ homomorphisms
of Abelian groups with $\psi\circ\phi=\text{id}_A$. I claim that $B$
is the direct sum of $\phi(A)$ and $\ker\psi$.

If $b\in B$, then $\psi(b-\phi(\psi(b)))=\psi(b)-\psi(\phi(\psi(b)))=
\psi(b)-\psi(b)=0$ (using $\psi\circ\phi=\text{id}_A$). Therefore
$b-\phi(\psi(b))\in\ker\psi$, and $b$ is the sum of an element of $\phi(A)$
(namely $\phi(\psi(b))$) and an element of $\ker\psi$
(namely $b-\phi(\psi(b))$).

If $b\in \phi(A)\cap\ker \psi$, then $\psi(b)=0$ and $b=\phi(a)$ for
some $a$. Therefore $0=\psi(\phi(a))=a$ and so $b=\phi(a)=0$.

As $\phi(A)+\ker\psi=B$ and $\phi(A)\cap\ker\psi=\{0\}$
then $B=\phi(A)\oplus\ker\psi$.

Comment: In the first line, $\psi(b-\psi(\phi(b)))$ do you perhaps mean $\psi(b-\phi(\psi(b)))$

Comment: @LordSharktheUnkown Thanks for the help! Once I do change the order of the functions I follow the proof. I can't see where you used the abelian nature of the groups though - would the result hold for non-abelian groups as well? Also since we do not know that A and B are finite, this does not necessarily mean that it works for the direct product as well right?

Comment: @Silvan_peters This does work for non-Abelian groups. Of course there, you need to be more careful about orders of operations.

Comment: No, it does not work for non-abelian groups (at least not with the same conclusion). One would only get a semidirect product.